# Tomcat servlet mapping error after Broken pipe error

Tags: tomcat, servlets

We have implemented Servlet 3.0 AsyncContext in Tomcat Version:7.0.23.

It is runing in `RHEL 6.1 using OpenJDK version 1.6.0_24,64-bit` server

The app is working fine for most part.
When there is some disturbance in the network, the update from the server is not able to reach the client as there is a  "`ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe`" exception. which is caught and ignored.

This happens in the line,

```
asyncContext.getResponse().getWriter().println(updateStr);
```

After this Tomcat goes crazy and is routing URLs to unexpected servlets.
For example with a mapping of /query to a servlet called SessionManager, the URL `mysite.com/index.html` is routed to the SessionManager servlet.
Only restart of tomcat solves the problem.

Any pointers on why this is happening and how to solve this?

Just to add more data, the following is the stack trace of the exception.

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:307)
    at com.management.TestHandler$TestInfo.statusUpdate(TestHandler.java:638)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.publish(TestObject.java:1626)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.handlePublish(TestObject.java:1421)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.executeCommand(TestObject.java:1371)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.executeCommand(TestObject.java:1388)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.executeCommand(TestObject.java:1388)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.executeCommand(TestObject.java:1388)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.executeCommand(TestObject.java:1388)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.executeCommand(TestObject.java:1388)
    at com.chakra.ipbtt.TestObject.executeTest(TestObject.java:1791)
    at com.management.TestHandler.executeTest(TestHandler.java:420)
    at com.management.TestHandler.handleNewTest(TestHandler.java:222)
    at com.management.TestMgr.processRequest(TestMgr.java:71)
    at com.management.TestMgr.doPost(TestMgr.java:105)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.management.SessionMgr.processRequest(SessionMgr.java:131)
    at com.management.SessionMgr.doPost(SessionMgr.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.management.SessionsFilter.doFilter(SessionsFilter.java:127)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:462)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:789)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:341)
    ... 48 more`
```

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution or the cause?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug on the side of Tomcat.

First, I would try to update to Apache Tomcat 7.0.**64**.

Second, I would try to update to Java 6u**45**.

Answer (score 0):

We had the similar issue in our server-side. It turned out that the dataset we were sending in response was getting blocked at Filter level as the data was very huge and it blew up at this level.

```
@Component
public class TrackingFilter implements TraceRepository, Filter {
/**
* Few other business relarted code
*
byte[] bytes = pw.toByteArray();
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
}
```